# FileInputStream in Fragment giving FileNotFound exception

Tags: java, android, fragment

I'm attempting to save integers on internal storage using a fragment class, and seem to be able to use FileOutputStream to save files, but the program never seems to be able to find them once created.

Here's the relevant Java class:

```
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_preferences, container, false);

    final SeekBar s1 = (SeekBar) root.findViewById(R.id.s1Bar);

    Button button = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.savebutton);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int spi = s1.getProgress();

            String fileContents = String.valueOf(spi);

            try {
                FileOutputStream outputStream = getActivity().openFileOutput("myText.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                outputStream.write(fileContents.getBytes());
                outputStream.close();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "File saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
            catch (Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "File not saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });

    s1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean fromUser) {
            spicinessText.setText("Spiciness: "+i);
            int spiciness = i;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    try {

        FileInputStream inputStream = getActivity().openFileInput("myText.txt");


        String m = inputStream.toString();

        int c = Integer.parseInt(m);

        s1.setProgress(c);

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "File Received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "File not received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    return root;
}
```

Upon loading the Fragment, it always gives the FileNotFound exception, even if I've created it earlier. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the file only after the button is clicked but you are trying to read the file immediately after the fragment is created. This is why you are getting FileNotFound Exception.

put the file read code inside a method and call it anytime after the button is clicked. Something like this:

```
public void readFile(){
     try {

        FileInputStream inputStream = getActivity().openFileInput("myText.txt");
        String m = inputStream.toString();
        int c = Integer.parseInt(m);
        s1.setProgress(c);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "File Received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "File not received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }
}



public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                     final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_preferences, container, false);

    final SeekBar s1 = (SeekBar) root.findViewById(R.id.s1Bar);

    Button button = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.savebutton);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int spi = s1.getProgress();
            String fileContents = String.valueOf(spi);

            try {
                FileOutputStream outputStream = getActivity().openFileOutput("myText.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                outputStream.write(fileContents.getBytes());
                outputStream.close();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "File saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                readFile(); // FILE IS CREATED NOW. SO YOU CAN READ IT.
            }
            catch (Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "File not saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });

    s1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean fromUser) {
            spicinessText.setText("Spiciness: "+i);
            int spiciness = i;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    return root;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. When I move the file reading function to another method, it still cannot find the file, even if I just created it.

Comment: did you call the function after the saveButton is clicked ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try creating a File object, then calling exists(), canRead(), or canExecute() methods to test if the directory works?
I encountered the same issue today, which took me about two hours to partially figured out. It was so annoying. Depending on how your class code is structured, Java does not allow you to read text file within the unit test. Try reading it in the main method.
Let me know if it works :)